# I want to make use of FromSql instead of FromSqlRaw in my project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
private CompletedViewModel GetLatestCandidateBySchoolId(RegistrationViewModel regVM)
{
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Candidates " +
                      "WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName " + 
                      "AND MiddleName = @MiddleName AND DOB = @DateOfBirth";

    var candidate = _context.Candidates
                            .FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery,
                                        new SqlParameter("@FirstName", regVM.FirstName),
                                        new SqlParameter("@LastName", regVM.Surname),
                                        new SqlParameter("@MiddleName", regVM.MiddleName),
                                        new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", regVM.DateOfBirth)
                                       )
                            .FirstOrDefault();

    return GenerateCompletedViewModel(candidate);
}
```

This is a part of my project, I'm currently trying to incorporate the `.FromSql()` method instead of `.FromSqlRaw()` that I used here, but I keep getting this error

> No overload for method 'FromSql' takes 5 arguments

Please what could the issue be?

I'll appreciate any help I can get.

I want to make use of `.FromSql()` in EF Core 7.0.

Comment: If you [look at the official documentation for `.FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql?view=efcore-7.0), and actually **read** the error message - it should be pretty clear. `.FromSql` does **NOT** take a bunch of `SqlParameter` objects as parameters - you need to adapt your code accordingly

Comment: Additionally, while adapting the code, it's **not okay** to use string concatenation instead of parameters to include that information with the query (though EF can work some magic with string interpolation to parameterize things that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private CompletedViewModel GetLatestCandidateBySchoolId(RegistrationViewModel regVM)
{
    var candidate = _context.Candidates.FromSql(
$"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Candidates WHERE FirstName = {regVM.FirstName} AND LastName = {regVM.LastName} AND MiddleName = {regVM.MiddleName} AND DOB = {regVM.DateOfBirth}"
           ).FirstOrDefault();

    return GenerateCompletedViewModel(candidate);
}
```

One important note on this: it's necessary for the SQL to be *one interpolated string* for the query parameterization to work correctly. This is why I rearranged things so the SQL is all on one line by itself. Get this even a little bit wrong, and suddenly you have a massive gaping security issue.